# Clear out the STL list of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, stl

I have defined a list of pointers. How should I free all these pointers before clearing the list? What is the best approach to erase all list members? In below program, is it required to free memory allocated for struct?? See my inline comments.

```
struct MyStruct {
    char *data;
    int len;
};

typedef std::list<struct MyStruct *> myStruct_list;
myStruct_list l_list;

/* Prepare a list */

for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    struct MyStruct *s = (MyStruct *)malloc(sizeof(struct MyStruct));
    s->data = (char*)malloc(MAX_LEN);
    get_random_data(s->data,size);
    s->len = strlen(s->data);
    l_list.push_back(s);
}


/* Delete all members from a list */

myStruct_list::iterator it;
for (it = l_list.begin(); it != l_list.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it) {
        free(*it);       // --->> do I need to free (*it)->data ?????
    }
}
l_list.clear();
```

Comment: Why are you even using pointers here?  I see no reason to do so and if you remove them then you don't have to worry about leaking :)

Comment: Why are you using malloc? Half of this code looks more like c than c++.

Comment: `std::list<struct MyStruct *>::iterator it;` I'm sorry, are you from the past? Seriously though, if you're not working with some legacy system here, you really need to update your learning material.

Comment: Sorry but this is sample program. I just started learning C++. I want to understand the pointers and STL containers. So I have written sample program.

Comment: `s[len] = '\0';` will not end well, instead of allocating and terminating the string yourself, consider using `std::string`.

Comment: @M.Rock : Your code represents how C++ probably (since I'm not old enough to know for sure) looked like around the year 2003. Things have really changed since then : *please* look for an updated textbook.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to understand is there any memory leak in below program?

Yes you have it right here:

```
p = (char*)malloc(MAX_LEN);
p = (char *)buf;
```

you allocate memory and assign it to `p` and next line you loose it. So:

1. You should not use `malloc()` in C++ programs unless you need to pass data that would be managed by C code
2. You should use special data structure like `std::string` etc to manage your data.
3. If you still need to allocate dynamic memory use smart pointers.

> How should I debug if there is any memory leak?

You would not create them in the first place. For example, how could you write `get_random_str` (assuming you really have to allocate it using `malloc`):

```
using spchar = std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype(std::free) *>;

spchar get_random_str( int len )
{
    spchar s( static_cast<char *>( malloc( len + 1 ) ), std::free );
    static const char alphanum[] =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
     for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
         s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
     }

     s[len] = '\0';
     return s;
 }
```

Note, I did not compile this code, it's to show you the idea.

Update: looks like you think that this code:

```
p = (char *)buf;
```

would copy string from `buf` to `p`, which is not the case. Instead you make `p` point to memory of `buf` loosing old value that `malloc()` returned before (hence creating memory leak) and you assign that adress of `buf` to `data` which leads to UB when you call `free()` on it, so what you  need instead:

```
strncpy( p, buf, MAX_LEN );
```

but even that is not necessary as you do not really need `buf` at all:

```
void myClass::fillData(void) 
{
    s = (MyStruct *)malloc(sizeof(struct MyStruct));
    s->data = (char*)malloc(MAX_LEN);
    get_random_str(s->data,950);
    s->len = strlen(s->data);
    l_list.push_back(s);
}
```

but this is more C code, using some C++ syntax. You should get newer compiler and textbook if you really want to learn C++.

Comment: You are right. it might be used by some C code in future. That's why I used malloc.

Comment: You can still deallocate memory from malloc using smart pointers and custom deleter. But bigger problem you are writing C code, not C++

Comment: @M.Rock If you are writing code so it may be used by C in the future, you are writing C code. If your code is *not* C, then using `malloc` is the least of your concern when time comes to porting it.

Comment: I assigned to p. And then I assigned this p to struct data member. So i don't loose it but I have first list member which pointing to this. I can keep track of this. Also, it seems in my environment they haven't upgraded g++. It seems they still using older version. So smart pointers are not supported.

Comment: @M.Rock you do loose it, I copied 2 lines of code from your question where you assign result of `malloc` to `p` and next line you assign `buf` to `p`, losing address of memory that `malloc` returned before. And assigning `buf` to `p` creates another problem - you call `std::free` with `buf` which is UB as well. Looks like you wanted `strcpy( p, buff );` instead of `p = buff;` Learn about pointers if you want to use them.

Comment: Updated the code. Now do you think any memory leak? When I destroy this list, I don't know whether I have to destroy each of these pointers? I mean in destructor, do i need to delete (*it)->data before deleting (*it)?

Answer (score -2):

Delete elements using lambda function in `for_each`:

```
std::for_each(l_list.begin(), l_list.end(), [](const MyStruct* elem){if(elem) free(elem)});
```

And clear pointers:

```
l_list.clear();
```

Comment: A much better suggestion would be to have a `std::list` of `std::unique_ptr`s, which would guarantee destruction of the pointed-to structures at the time of the list's destruction. This is, of course, assuming that the OP really needs to store pointers to the structures in the first place...

Comment: imho the answer to "Why do I have a memory leak?" should be "because you are using raw pointers". Freeing them fights the symptom not the cause ;)

Comment: Not the dv, but `if(elem)` is superfluous, it's legal to call `free` on a null pointer. (Also, pretty much purely opinion based but `std::for_each` seems a little bloated compared to a range based for loop `for( const auto elem : l_list )`).

Comment: Why is this being so harshly downvoted? It answers the ops question specifically for code they already have...